# Impersonate an user email to google service account

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-authentication, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to upload the files to google drive. For this I have an service account with domain wide authority enabled. "`@xyx.com`" is my domain. I have a common "`abc@xyz.com`" google drive.

Google service account is "`xxx@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com`". I need to upload the files to "`abc@xyz.com`". I tried to impersonate the "`abc@xyz.com`" to the service account.

Below is my code

```html
public static DriveService AuthenticateServiceAccount(string serviceAccountEmail, string keyFilePath)
        {
            // check the file exists
            if (!File.Exists(keyFilePath))
            {
                return null;
            }

            //Google Drive scopes Documentation:   https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes
            string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,  // view and manage your files and documents
                                             DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata,  // view and manage its own configuration data
                                             DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,   // view and manage files created by this app
                                             DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadata,
                                             DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadataReadonly,   // view metadata for files
                                             DriveService.Scope.DrivePhotosReadonly,
                                             DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly,   // view files and documents on your drive
                                             DriveService.Scope.DriveScripts };  // modify your app scripts     


            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            try
            {
                ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                    {
                        Scopes = scopes,
                        User = "abc@xyz.com",
                    }.FromCertificate(certificate));
                DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "CIM_GD_UPLOAD",
                });
                return service;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method.", Uri:""
```

I am using **google api v3**.

Please help me, is it possible to impersonate an user account to a service account? or guide me the correct way to upload/ retrieve the files from google drive.

Comment: you need to have the whole thing setup through G-Suite - in case that wasnt done.

Comment: did you found any solution for this ?

Comment: Google doc said the best is to use service account impersonation. I tried it with the C# Google API client and it never worked. The only thing working for me right now is to use service account key (https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#auth-decision-tree)

Answer (score -1):

Referring to [Google Drive API Authorization](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth), you need to authorize request with OAuth 2.0 to be able to access Google APIs. First step in the authorization process is to obtain OAuth 2.0 credentials from the [Google API Console](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=cloudconsole&passive=1209600&osid=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole.developers.google.com%2F%3Fref%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fprotocols%2FOAuth2&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole.developers.google.com%2F%3Fref%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fprotocols%2FOAuth2&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin). Same process goes when you use service account, you have to generate service-account credentials then [delegate domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority).

You may want to try as stated in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests):

> If you have delegated domain-wide access to the service account and you want to impersonate a user account, specify the email address of the user account with the `setServiceAccountUser` method of the `GoogleCredential` factory. For example:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
    .setServiceAccountId(emailAddress)
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("MyProject.p12"))
    .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(SQLAdminScopes.SQLSERVICE_ADMIN))
    .setServiceAccountUser("user@example.com")
    .build();
```

> Use the `GoogleCredential` object to call Google APIs in your application.

Comment: how can we add impersonating email address in c# ?